# Transformation of a linear independent set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, solution-verification

### Question

Let  $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ be vectors in a vector space $V$ and let $T:V→W$ be a linear transformation.
if $T(v_1),\cdots,T(v_n)$ is linearly independent in $W$, show that $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ is linearly independent in $V$.

### Here's what i have so far:

if $T(v_1),\cdots,T(v_n)$ is linearly independent, there exists scalars equal to $0$ such that:
$$c_1T(v_1)+c_2T(v_2)+\cdots +c_nT(v_n)=0\\T(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n)=0$$

because $T$ is a linear transformation.

Where do I go from here? Do I need to prove that $T$ is injective of can i just state that $v_1,\cdots,v_n$  is linearly independent because I stated earlier that the scalars are equal to $0$?

Comment: There needs to be more to $T$, as a projecting basis vectors to a subspace does not keep linear independence.

Comment: @Cbjork He just needs to pull back linear independence.  The assumption is that the image is linearly independent.

Comment: Ah I should read the question

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive.  If you have a nontrivial linear combination among $v_1,\ldots, v_n$, then what happens upon applying $T$

Comment: @IBWiglin can you rephrase that? linear algebra isnt my strong suit. So all of the terminology goes over my head. sorry :(

Answer (score 7):

You want to show $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are linearly independent. Suppose they are not. Then there are scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ (not all zero) so that $c_1v_1+\ldots +c_nv_n=0$. Then $$ T(c_1v_1+\ldots +c_nv_n)=T(0)=0.$$ So $c_1T(v_1)+\ldots +c_nT(v_n)=0$, which means that $T(v_1), \ldots, T(v_n)$ are *not* linearly independent.  This contradiction means the assumption that the $v_i$s are linearly dependent is false, so they are indeed linearly independent.

Comment: i wrote down that if v_1,…,v_n are linearly dependent then the scalars c_1,...,c_n are not all zero which contradicts the statement that c_1,...,c_n are zero. Will that work? Does it make sense?

Comment: What is the definition of linear independence you are using?